# Is is possible to use remote desktop to a Mac via direct cable or wireless?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, mac-mini, remote-desktop

I develop on Windows, but I need a Mac for iPhone development.  So I'm thinking of getting a Mac mini or a MacBook for the Mac part, and connecting to it as needed from my Windows machine. A mini, in particular, doesn't come with a monitor or keyboard or mouse, so this would be the *only* way to use it.

The question is: sometimes I travel and so I'm away from my network.  In this situation, is it possible to plug a cable directly from my Windows machine to the Mac and do remote desktop this way, or do both machines have to be on the same network and router and the sharing done via IP address in the usual way? Alternatively, can I skip the network entirely and remote desktop machine to machine via wireless signal?

Comment: a mini is just a desktop, you can use any usb keyboard/mouse and display with it.  You could also use a KVM to share with your windows desktop.

Comment: @Jason: You're right.  I should make that more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, it's important to note that Apple's Remote Desktop is not Microsoft's Remote Desktop, and the two are not interchangeable. That said, you can still use various VNC products to connect from the Windows machine to the Mac.

From there, it's standard networking. If you want to leave the Mac Mini at home, you'll need to make sure that you can access the required ports, whether by port forwarding, or by an SSH tunnel/VPN allowing you to connect to your home network.

If you bring the Mac Mini with you, then you can easily create an ad hoc Wi-Fi network to connect them both too, in which case they will be on the same network, and you can connect that way. (You may need a monitor and keyboard attached to the Mac Mini at some point to configure this.)

Additionally, the Mac can automatically make any standard Ethernet cable into a crossover cable, such that an Ethernet cable connecting your Mac to your PC will create a network connection for the two machines, which, again, you can use as a standard network to connect from one to the other.

The network can be WiFi, direct point to point ethernet, point to point thunderbolt, point to point firewire or over a wired switched network of any of the above carriers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough answer.  Do you know if the "various VNC products" are any good?  I've experimented with a number of them and the quality is often pretty bad.

Comment: I don't have much experience with them, sorry.  I did use Screen Sharing over a wired connection for a time several years ago, and it was surprisingly better than my "typical" VNC experience on other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

**Over Ethernet:**
If you would be primarily using wireless on both machines and will not be using Ethernet on the Windows machine or the Mac, then you could configure the LAN/Ethernet on the Windows machine and the Mac as a [Private Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) and use it whenever necessary.

For example, the Windows machine could have its LAN set to a fixed IPv4 address of 10.0.0.1 and the Mac could have its LAN set to a fixed IPv4 address of 10.0.0.2. In both the cases, let the subnet be configured to 255.255.255.0. You can then connect the machines using an Ethernet cable and you should be able to do do anything on the network (remote desktop using `Screen Sharing` or `VNC`, `ssh` or file sharing).

**Over wireless:**
Machine to machine through wireless could be done similarly, but it would disrupt your wireless connection to the Internet. If speed is not a concern, you could have both the machines connected to the Internet over WiFi and use a free program like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) to connect.

Windows VNC clients (to connect to a Mac that has `Screen Sharing` enabled):

- TightVNC
- UltraVNC

Answer (score 0):

Any cable that will carry an IP based network will allow you to visually screen share a Mac - either with a virtual display or mirroring the current contents of the display. Wireless works well since it also networks and in most cases is fast enough to carry the screen data unless you have several 30 inch displays and are encoding the full bit depth of color information.

This is enabled in the sharing preference pane under **Screen Sharing** or **Remote Management** and uses a VNC based protocol. [Apple's remote desktop software](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/) integrates best with many options to reduce bandwidth since the remote mac is encoding the screen contents and sending it over the network. For this reason, a high speed network is ideal - but you don't need to be on the local subnet if you are using iCloud or another location service to determine the IPv6 address of the Mac being observed.

As the other answers and comments have indicated that some clients are lacking, for my money, Apple's client and the one from [Edovia called Screens](http://edovia.com/en/screens.html) are head and shoulders above the rest. The screens app is also nice as it includes a location service if you are remote and need to locate the IP / port of the Mac if it is located behind a router that uses NAT/PMP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more definitive answer using TightVNC.

I've been connecting via my Wifi but it's slow at times. 
I wanted to make it faster since my Mac Mini sits on the same desk where my laptop is.

**Steps**

*Prerequisite*:

A. make sure your Mac is on and you can control via VNC (see : [http://www.howtogeek.com/214220/how-to-access-your-macs-screen-from-windows-and-vice-versa/ for more](http://www.howtogeek.com/214220/how-to-access-your-macs-screen-from-windows-and-vice-versa/) )

B. make sure you have TightVNC (that's what I use) on your Win10 machine.

1. Connect your ethernet cable to your Mac and Win10 computer.
2. On the Mac go to System Preferences...

[image: system preferences]

3. Choose the Network (icon) option

[image: network option]

4. You will see a window which allows you to set up the ethernet and it is probably already configured for you.

**Please NOTE I've updated this section for a consistent IP ADDRESS you need to enter the value manually (configure it one time on Mac) so the Mac will use the SAME IP Address every time**

[image: enter IP Address Manually]

**Necessity of Manual IP Configuration**

The reason we do the manual setup is so when you power down your Mac and power up the next time, you do not get an assigned (random) ip address, but instead it will be set to this same value each time.

You want the same value so you know what to use in the VNC program.

**Yet Another Note**

When I changed to manual setup then my connection was extremely slow.  I couldn't get it to be faster.  I switched back to automatic configuration (see next image) and it was faster.  However, that means keeping my wifi running on the Mac so I can initially connect get the assigned IP address and then connecting the 2nd time each day over ethernet with assigned ip address.
Try multiple options see what is best for you:

[image: automatic DHCP]

5. Get the IP ADDRESS
   This is the important part. 
   Make note of that IP Address starting with 169 in the image.

That is the IP address you will use to connect to the Mac.
That is the effective address of the Mac that your Win10 machine has assigned to the Mac.
Now, I'm assuming that you've set up your Mac so it can be remotely controlled --- I won't go through that here.

6. Start TightVNC on your Win10 machine
7. type in the IP Address from above and connect.
8. Type in your "connection password" (which you previously set up on your Mac) when prompted and everything should work.

You can see your connection status from Win10 at Settings...Ethernet...Network and Sharing Center...:

[image: Settings and Network]

When you click Network and Sharing on the left you'll see:

[image]

Here's how it will be setup on Win10 side:
[image: win10 ethernet setup]

Finally, click the Ethernet link in the middle right and you'll see a status and should see more bytes received than sent over time --- that is the remote Mac sending data to your computer via VNC.

[image: ethernet status]

**Also notice that it shows 1.0GBPS** (Gigabit per second = 1000 MBPS)
That's probably much faster than your wireless network and this keeps that traffic off there.

Here's my wifi connection -- notice that it is only about 72 MBPS (about 1/10 of ethernet).

[image]