# Remote desktop from a mac to windows machine, using direct connection eg Ethernet

Tags: macos, windows, remote-desktop, ethernet

I work primarily off a Mac-book. I have a windows machine on which I do some .net development. I simply need to be able to use windows remote desktop on my mac to remote desktop to the windows machine, but not over internet. I want the connection to be established over local WiFi, or over direct Ethernet connection between the two machines, if that is even possible. There are many postings on this topic, but non specific to my case.

The closest answer I have come across is [this here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69374/88885), which only mentions the possibilities, but not the implementation.

Are there any resources I could use to help me set this up, or if anyone knows how to?

Answer (score 1):

In the server name merely specify the local IP address of the computer and in the username field specify the username *Fully Qualified.* EG COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME on the PC and then the password for that account.

That should be all you need to do: merely specify the local IP address of the target PC.

Comment: this sounds very straight forward. Should I be worried about the local IP address changing, and if I need to assign a static address to the windows machine or something like that?

Comment: You can but DHCP will always grab the same IP address unless you have a VERY busy and full network. Probably don't need to...